# Is there any regex to find localization strings such as en_US (or generic xx_YY)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am currently using a simple `indexOf()` method applied by using an array of localization/regions, such as `en_US`, `es_ES`, `en_GB`, and so on. However, I do not have a complete list of them so it's almost impossible to me to go through any specific case.

The question therefore is: can I use some regex to recognize a pattern such as xx_YY having xx as lower-case and YY as upper-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `[a-z]{2}[_][A-Z]{2}` .

```js
var str = "xy_YY";
var reg = "[a-z]{2}[_][A-Z]{2}";
if (str.match(reg))
  alert("match");
```

Answer (score 1):

My thougths:

```
\b[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}\b
```

If yo need grops and read them so just

```
\b([a-z]{2})_([A-Z]{2})\b
```

Answer (score 1):

if there are no numbers this should do the job `^[a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][A-Z]`